# no need of recompile when configuration changes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET Core, I was reading a book which says:

> ***In ASP.NET Core, you finally get the ability to edit a file and have the configuration of your application automatically update,
>   without having to recompile or restart.***

and it also says that when using strong typed setting with IOptions interface:

> ***Registers the IOptions interface in the DI container as a singleton, with the final bound POCO object in the Value property.***

So here is my question, if the implementation of IOptions is singleton, which means the app will get same instance of the service all the time. If thats the case, when the configuration files change, how can the app doesn't need to recompile to reflect the latest change? ( if the IOptions is singleton, the POCO object is always the same too)

Comment: @John   but the IOptions<T> .Value is singleton too. how can the app not recompile to create a new instance of  IOptions<T> to reflect the latest change?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IOptions<T>` interface then `Value` property will always return the same value set during configuration. In order to get updated values every time file has been changed you should inject `IOptionsMonitor<T>` or `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` interface.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<SomeOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigSection"));
```

**TestController.cs** (with `IOptions`)

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<SomeOptions> _options;

    public TestController(IOptions<SomeOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetConfig()
    {
        return Json(_options.Value); //returns same value every time
    }
}
```

**TestController.cs** (with `IOptionsMonitor`)

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<SomeOptions> _options;

    public TestController(IOptionsMonitor<SomeOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetConfig()
    {
        return Json(_options.CurrentValue); //returns recalculated value
    }
}
```